# Hello! In my code, EmailField and PasswordField dont work

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms, email-validation

Even password and confirm password don' match, it doesn't give me feedback about that. Also even I write email like that 'vmdfjk@hot' my code except this email I dont know why and Im really confused. Thanks alredy!

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, redirect, url_for, session, logging, request
import socket
import sqlite3
from wtforms import Form, BooleanField, StringField, PasswordField, validators, ValidationError, SubmitField ,EmailField
from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt
from wtforms.validators import *
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key="nane"

class RegisterForm(Form):
    name = StringField("İsim Soyisim :", validators=[validators.DataRequired(), validators.Length(min=4, max=25)])
    username = StringField("Kullanici Adi :", validators=[validators.DataRequired(), validators.Length(min=5, max=15)])
    email = EmailField("Email Adresi :", validators=[validators.DataRequired(), validators.Email(message="Lütfen geçerli bir adres girin!")])
    password = PasswordField("Parola : ", validators=[
        validators.DataRequired(message="Parola girin!"),
        validators.EqualTo("confirm", message="Parolaniz uyusmadi!")
    ])
    confirm = PasswordField("Parolayi yeniden girin : ")


@app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])  # METHODS, BU URL HEM GET HEM DE POST REQUEST ALABİLİR DEMEKTİR.
def register():
    form = RegisterForm(request.form)

    if request.method == "POST" and form.validate:

        flash("Başarıyla kayıt oldunuz", "success")

        return redirect(url_for("index"))  # fonksiyonu index olan url adresine gider
    else:
        pass
    return render_template("register.html", form=form)
```

I am expecting to work correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a call to `validate`, the associated parentheses are missing. For this reason, any attempt to validate returns a positive result.

```py
@app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"]) 
def register(): 
    form = RegisterForm(request.form)
    if request.method == "POST" and form.validate():
        flash("Başarıyla kayıt oldunuz", "success")
        return redirect(url_for("index"))
    return render_template("register.html", form=form)
```

Comment: Fixed!! I am so greatful thank you so much!